# UI5 using something like .. in bindingpath

Tags: binding, sapui5

I using a oData-Model that returns for .../User a list like that:

```
[
    {
      Id: 5
      Name: "name",
      Desc: "desc",
      IsEditable: false,
      Items: [
        { itemName: "Name1" },
        { itemName: "Name2" },
        { itemName: "Name3" },
        { itemName: "Name4" }
      ]
    },
    ...
]
```

I bind this to my xml view like that:

```
<View binding="model>/User(5)">

    <Text text="model>Name" />
    <Text text="model>Desc" />

    <List items="{model>Items}" >
        <CustomListItem>
            <input text="{model>itemName}" editable="{model>../IsEditable}" />
        </CustomListItem>
    </List>

</View>
```

So now i would like to disable the input by its parent "IsEditable" proppertie.

How i can make this happen?

Comment: No, there is no *parent* operator or something similar. You need a second association from Items to User (i.e. do a reverse of the User -> Items association). Oooor you can introduce a second model (since you can bind almost infinite models to a view).

Comment: Since you hard coded the user number, would something like `model>/User(5)/IsEditable` work? Or are you looking at looping over users, then looping over items. Is `Items` a navigation?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you have to edit your code like this:
(Relative binding in JSON Models without a "/", absolute with a "/")

```
<List items="{model>/Items}" >
<CustomListItem>
<Input value="{model>itemName}" editable="{model>/IsEditable}" />
</CustomListItem>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer but i picked a bad example. I edit my question. Maybe you have again an awnser.

Comment: As I'm thinking that you're new to SAPUI5 please refer to this DemoKit https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/ and go through the walkthrough presented there. Everything about JSON Models is also described in other posts. But I'm seeing a bigger problem in your understanding of binding in UI5.

Comment: Hey i working with ui5 for 6 month... And i think i understand the basics of binding... i often have this kinde of problem by odata binding. So i just wanted to ask if there is a way to create a binding to a property of the parent binding

Comment: But I can't see your problem. What are you trying to achieve? How should your view look like? If you provide a JSON Model with the specific user data out of the user array then it would work as i provided it. you don't have to do a binding in the view because you bind the model in your controller to the view and then you can access it.
Furthermore, there are a view errors in your code. Like this, your code isn't running properly, so please fix this first, before asking questions about things you couldn't have tested, because your code isn't working